# Laravel: How to make a stand-alone piece of functionality?

Tags: laravel, class, oop, laravel-5

There is a UserVerification service that I use in multiple applications. One can submit its email/number to this service, the service verifies that the submitter is actually who he/she claims, then based on its existence in users table, it registers or logs in the user and returns a token.

I want to implement this process as a separate piece of functionality. Here are choices came to my mind:

1. Implement this as a trait,
2. Implement this as a class,
3. Implement this as a service provider,
4. In case of using [nwidart](https://nwidart.com) module, I can implement this as a module (it is applicable only in case of usage of this package).

I would like to know from software engineering and object oriented, what is the standard and best solution to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it depends a lot on how it works. If it's a one time call and result, then a service/helper would be best, but if it a multi step thing with a state, then a trait would work better. In all cases, your question is too broad.

Comment: @N69S it is multistep. Verification is via SMS service, a user must submit a code that he has received from SMS or Email